# Get all list's values using REST API - ERROR

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, rest, api

I'm trying to get all values from a list and print it to screen.

I have a column named 'tz' and I want to print it only.

I use this code, but I am getting an error:

> Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference"

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    $.ajax({
               url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items",
               method: "GET",
               headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
               success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) {
                       for (i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++)
                       {
                            alert(data.d.results[i].tz);
                       }
                    }       
              },
              error: function (data) {
                  alert("Error: "+ data);
             }
      });
});
```

Comment: You may want to change that ``alert`` to ``console.log`` and inspect it in F12 Dev console.... unless you really want to spend hours a day clicking OK in  alert boxes

Answer (score 0):

You have used `$.ajax({ });` 2 times. check the modified code below

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    $.ajax({
               url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items",
               method: "GET",
               headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
               success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) {
                       for (i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++)
                       {
                            alert(data.d.results[i].tz);
                       }
                    }       
              },
              error: function (data) {
                  alert("Error: "+ data);
             }
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: hey, same error :(

Comment: try like this `data.d.results[i]["tz"]`

Comment: ``["tz"]`` and ``.tz`` do exactly the same. Add a ``console.log(data)`` inside the succes function and check the F12 console if the data structure you expect is there